# hard time upgrading navigation part of Ionic3 code to ionic4 using router

Tags: router, ionic4

hi this is my first question in stackoverflow, any help is highly appreciated:

basically my code displays two pages where navigation can be done on same page or to other page.I am finding no way to upgrade my code to Ionic4 using router.

my **service.ts** in Ionic3 is:

```
_oneNav: Nav = null;

get oneNav(): Nav {
    return this._oneNav;
}
set oneNav(value: Nav) {
    this._oneNav = value;
}

_twoNav: Nav = null;
get twoNav(): Nav {
    return this._twoNav;
}
set twoNav(value: Nav) {
    this._twoNav = value;
}

_isOn: boolean = false;

get isOn(): boolean {
    return this._isOn;
}
set isOn(value: boolean) {
    this._isOn = value;
}



pushTwo(page: any, params: any) {
    console.log("pushTwo",this.isOn);
    (this.isOn) ?
        this.twoNav.setRoot(page, params):
        //this.twoNav.push(page, params);
        this.oneNav.push(page, params);
}


pushOne(page: any, params: any) {
    this.oneNav.push(page, params);
}

setRootOne(page: any, params: any) {
    this.oneNav.setRoot(page, params);
}

onSplitPaneChanged(isOn) {
    // set local 'isOn' flag...
    this.isOn = isOn;
    // if the nav controllers have been instantiated...
    if (this.oneNav && this.twoNav) {
        (isOn) ? this.activateSplitView() :
                 this.deactivateSplitView();
    }
}
activateSplitView() {
    let currentView = this.oneNav.getActive();
        if (currentView.component.prototype
            instanceof _TwoPage) {
            // if the current view is a 'Two' page...
            // - remove it from the 'one' nav stack...
            this.oneNav.pop();
            // - and add it to the 'two' nav stack...
            this.twoNav.setRoot(
                currentView.component,
                currentView.data);
        }
 }
deactivateSplitView() {
    let twoView = this.twoNav.getActive();
    if(!twoView){
        return;
    }

    if (twoView.component.prototype instanceof _TwoPage) {
        // if the current two view is a 'Two' page...
        let index = this.oneNav.getViews().length;
        // add it to the one view...
        this.oneNav.insert(
            index,
            twoView.component,
            twoView.data
    );
    }
}
```

**app.html** is:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-split-pane (ionChange)="service.onSplitPaneChanged($event._visible);">
      <ion-nav [root]="onePage" #oneNav></ion-nav>
      <ion-nav [root]="twoPage" #twoNav main></ion-nav>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-content>
```

i tried to import RouterOutlet from @ionic/angular but no success

Answer (score 0):

You need read the Ionic 4 migration guide where they defined routing migration also.
As i know default ionic routing (Push/pop) has been changed to angular routing and now you can rout to other page with href='link'.